# convert an unfair coin into a fair coin in Python 2.7

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, algorithms, python

Using Python 2.7. Suppose I have an unfair coin and I want to turn it into a fair coin using the following way,

1. Probability of generating head is equal for unfair coin;
2. Flip unfair coin and only accept head;
3. When a head is appearing, treat it as 1 (head for virtual fair coin), when another head is appearing, treat it as 0 (tail for virtual fair coin), next time when head appears, treat it as 1, next time treat as 0, ..., and so on.

Not sure if this method works? Actually I am not quite confident about the method above and also how to use `equalCoinHelper()` correctly (I mark my question in my code).

If anyone have any good ideas, it will be great.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
counter = 0

# 0.3 probability return head as 1
# 0.7 probability return tail as 0
def unFairCoin():
   if random.random() < 0.3:
       return 1
   else:
       return 0

# probability of generating 1 is equal, so keep 1 only
def equalCoinHelper():
    result = 0
    while result == 0:
        result = unFairCoin()

def equalDistribution():
    global counter
    # not think about how to leverage this better
    equalCoinHelper()
    counter += 1
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # generate 10 random 0/1 with equal probability
    print ([equalDistribution() for _ in range(10)])
```

Comment: The sequence this produces is 101010101..., always, right? How does this emulate a fair coin?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If you have an unfair coin, I guess you can correct it if you know the expected ratio of heads to tails.  What you have done is make a sequence of 1,0,1,0,1,...etc, so you have an equal number of heads and tails, and a head followed by a tail, ad infinitum, that's hardly random.

Comment: This looks a bit weird, why not just use ranndom.rand()<0.5?

Comment: @Alex, I just simulate an unfair coin.

Comment: @Did, fair coin produce 0 and 1 with equal probability, what is the issue if I produce 10101010...?

Comment: Key-word: `always`. Still no problem?

Comment: @Did, I understand my code has issues, the purpose of this question is I want to find if there are any new solutions (other than the method of flip twice and reject what we do not need), I think whether we could leverage the property that -- the probability of Head appear is always equal? That's the initial of my algorithm. Your ideas are appreciated.

Comment: @user247608, I want to develop some solutions which does not dependent on knowing `expected ratio of heads to tails`. I understand my code has issues, the purpose of this question is I want to find if there are any new solutions (other than the method of flip twice and reject what we do not need), I think whether we could leverage the property that -- the probability of Head appear is always equal? That's the initial of my algorithm. Your ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I did not even look at the code but only at the three steps method. (Still not sure you got the problem though, so let me just add it is massive and fundamental. Dunno if this will help.)

Comment: just a note on Python code: it's better to use 'if not result' than compare it to 0 and use some name instead of _

Comment: @Alex, agree with you and vote up. I think my code will generate sequence like 0 1 0 1 0 which is not correct as a pure random sequence. I am wondering if there are any solutions (of generating equal probability 0 and 1) which could leverage the property (of each time when a 1 is generated by unfair coin, the probability is equal)?

Comment: @Did, thanks and vote up. I think my code will generate sequence like 0 1 0 1 0 which is not correct as a pure random sequence. I am wondering if there are any solutions (of generating equal probability 0 and 1) which could leverage the property (of each time when a 1 is generated by unfair coin, the probability is equal)?

Answer (score 4):

You are just producing a deterministic sequence.

Try the following approach instead:

When you get $HH$ or $TT$, reject it.

When you get $HT$, treat it as head.

When you get $TH$ treat it as tail.

Comment: Thanks Siong, vote up and I fully understand your method. The purpose of this question is I want to find if there are any new solutions, I think whether we could leverage the property that -- the probability of Head appear is always equal? That's the initial of my algorithm.